# Why would mobileactivationd on macOS need to make external connections?

Tags: macos, network, ventura

I am on Ventura 13.3.1, and while using `sudo lsof -i`, like I usually do, I noticed `mobileactivationd` establishing a https connection to `humb-old.apple.com`.

Now, as long as I can remember, this process has never done this before. It always had many for : `[fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49167->[fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe33:4455]:49432`

But I always thought those were loopback addresses or something similar (e.g. not actual remote connections?). Until today, this is all I've ever seen. Not really sure what this process even does to be honest.

Comment: The IPV6 addresses you quote above are link-local, not loopback.  One of those addresses is the local machine, the other is somewhere else on your local network segment.

Comment: Considering they appear even when I am not connected to any network, I assume they are just local to my own machine? Any ideas why it's suddently used a remote connection that seems to belong to apple instead of link-local?